# Two kinds of documentation for Spring

Tags: java, spring, documentation

Can someone tell me why there are two kinds of documentation for Spring?

1. https://spring.io/docs/reference
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/

For example in 1. I can't find Spring MVC, in 2. I can. In 2. I can't find Spring Security, in 1. I can.

Feels like there are 2-3 kinds for everything in Spring.

Comment: 1. links to 2. - 1. is the entry point to the whole ecosystem, 2. is the documentation for a specific part of it.

Answer (score 1):

The first (https://spring.io/docs/reference)
is the reference of "all spring projects", the second (https://spring.io/docs/reference) is the documentation of the "spring framework", which is its own "spring project". Thus you find a link to the "spring framework" in the "all spring projects" documentation page, ending up on the link you posted.